# Two-fold fmap application

Tags: haskell, applicative

Lets assume we have

```
a :: IO (Maybe String)
b :: IO (Maybe String)

data Foo = Foo String String
```

And I want to obtain a `Maybe Foo` from `a` and `b`.

Currently, I'm doing this

```
do
  a' <- a
  b' <- b
  Foo <$> a' <*> b'
```

But, I feel like there should be an easier way,

```
(\x y -> Foo <$> x <*> y) <$> (Just <$> getLine) <*> (return Nothing)
```

Does the trick, but I don't want to create that ugly lambda there. Is there an operator like `<$>` but with two-fold application? Or is there any way to combine a `IO (Just a)`to have a single monad?

**Edit:**

I think the type signature is:

```
(Monad m, Monad n) => (a -> b -> c) -> (m (n a)) -> (m (n b)) -> (m (n c))
```

**Edit2:**

Sorry for not being clear, my data structure has more than two fields, it's actually a configuration structure having ~15 fields.

```
cfg <- Conf.load [ Conf.Required cfile ]

foo1 <- (Conf.lookup cfg "foo1" :: Maybe String )
foo2 <- Conf.lookup cfg "foo2"
foo3 <- Conf.lookup cfg "foo3"
foo4, foo5, foo6...

return $ Conf <$> foo1
              <*> foo2
              <*> foo3
              <*> foo4
              ...
```

Comment: You can use `liftM2 (\a b -> Foo <$> a <*> b)`

Comment: You could use `a, b :: MaybeT IO String`.  Then it's just `Foo <$> a <*> b`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest solution:

```
(liftA2 . liftA2) Foo :: IO (Maybe String) -> IO (Maybe String) -> IO (Maybe Foo)
```

`liftM2` also works. I prefer though the weakest acceptable solution (and with the coming Applicative-Monad superclassing with GHC 7.10 this will be wholly uncontroversial).

Alternatively, if `IO (Maybe a)` shows up frequently, you can use a monad transformer, and that way you can lift over any number of monads with `liftA2` / `liftM2`:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Applicative

liftA2 Foo :: MaybeT IO String -> MaybeT IO String -> MaybeT IO Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, while `Monad`s do not compose, `Applicative`s do. After wrapping all things in a suitable `newtype` you get this (see [`Control.Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.6.3/docs/Control-Compose.html#t::.) or [`Data.Functor.Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#v:Compose)):

```
import Control.Compose
a :: (IO :. Maybe) String
b :: (IO :. Maybe) String
result :: (IO :. Maybe) Foo
result = Foo <$> a <*> b
```